# How to run shell script in background while start?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script contain loop like this:

```
while true
do
  if ... ; then
    ...
  else
    ...
    break
  fi
done
```

I want this script to run backend while OS start. I have try to add this script into /etc/rc.d/local.rc as startup script. But OS start too long, and after OS start up, this script did not exist.

So how to add this script into backend while OS start up? And I need this script also could be start up by hand in backend. Thank you~

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  https://unix.stackexchange.com  Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  m https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why deleting https://stackoverflow.com/q/48727997/6309? it could help others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are scheduling on either Linux or Mac, then you can schedule through crontab.

Open terminal.

```
$crontab -e #use sudo to run as administrator 
#add below line
@reboot sh /absolute_path/script.sh
```

Give the absolute path of the script, save the crontab and exit.
The script will start running from the next reboot.